# Displaying Negative values in timeAgoFormat conversion in php

Tags: php

I have a situation where timeAgoFormat displaying result in negative value. like -18000 secs ago. but when i upload it to online server its displaying correct result. like 1 sec ago. why?
my code below.

`

class convertToAgo
{

```
function convert_datetime($str)
{
    list($date, $time) = explode(' ', $str);
    list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $date);
    list($hour, $minute, $second) = explode(':', $time);
    $timestamp = mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year);

    return $timestamp;
}

function makeAgo($timestamp)
{
    $difference = time() - $timestamp;

    $periods = array("sec", "min", "hr", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
    $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","1","10");

    $text = '';
    for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++)
    {
        $difference /= $lengths[$j];
    }

    $difference = round($difference);

    if($difference != 1)
    {
        $periods[$j].= "s";
    }

    $text = "$difference $periods[$j] ago<br />";

    return $text;
}
```

}

?>`

Veriable Definition
$myObject = new convertToAgo;

`$postdate = $row["postdate"];`
`$convertedTime = ($myObject -> convert_datetime($postdate));`
`$whenPost = ($myObject -> makeAgo($convertedTime));`

i am echoing $whenPost

Comment: Are you saying you get the correct result locally, but an incorrect result on the server? Can you provide details about what output you expect to see vs what you actually see? Also what is the value of `$postdate`?

Comment: i am saying, i am getting wrong result locally. but correct result on the server.

Comment: Okay ... so what is the value of `$postdate` locally?

Comment: echo $postdate result 2014-01-13 00:49:402014-01-12 12:13:072014-01-12 01:39:582014-01-09 23:55:01

Comment: Okay, then what do you get for `$convertedTime`?

Comment: 1389570580138952518713894871981389308101

Comment: Okay, compare those values to what you get when you run it on the server. It looks like you are converting 4 times locally, and concatenating the results.

Comment: 1390893121
2014-01-28 01:12:011390426459
2014-01-22 15:34:191390416585
2014-01-22 12:49:451390338323
2014-01-21 15:05:231390330158
2014-01-21 12:49:181390329632
2014-01-21 12:40:321390315851
2014-01-21 08:50:511390315677
2014-01-21 08:47:571390314972
2014-01-21 08:36:121390314839
2014-01-21 08:33:59 <br /> Result of echo $convertedTime; echo '<br />';
 echo $postdate; on Server

Comment: If it's not a silly question, are your local and remote servers on the same timezone? Looks like your local server is 5 hours ahead of the remote - a negative 'ago' is ahead, right?

Comment: lol... I am from India, and remote server belong to oakland my timezone is +5:30 hrs... Is this the problem?

Comment: It certainly sounds like it, I've had problems with this before in the UK when using US hosted servers. It's easily cured by adjusting the timezone in the PHP script before you process your code... Have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

Comment: So? How to change timezone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just based on what you said in the comments, try adding:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
```

to the top of your script and see what happens.

Comment: Does it effect the timeAgo on the server? @PeteR

Comment: It doesn't alter the time on the server or database (if you're using one), it just processes all time operations you use in the code using that timezone.